# LoRa Communication: Sending and Receiving Data with Raspberry Pi Receiver from Arduino Transceiver (RYLR896)

Tags: wireless, arduino

I'm using two RYLR896 Modules to setup a LoRa network. I'm using an Arduino Nano as my Transceiver and a Raspberry Pi 3B+ as my Receiver. While this verbage is currently accurate, this is intended to have bi-directional communication so that the Pi can send messages back to the Arduino, just FYI. In short, this Arduino has a button that, when pressed, sends a message to the Pi. The Pi receives this message and then sends a message to the Arduino, signaling an alarm state (this is all arbitrary). Once the Arduino receives the message from the Pi, it goes into an Alarm State and can only be cleared by an additional message from the Pi. NOTE: I have this working 100% with BLE (that is, the onboard BLE Chip on the Pi and an HC-05 on the Arduino) and am now adapting this same funcationality to LoRa for added range.

Arduino Side: So this side seems to work as intended.

I'm simply creating a Serial object `SoftwareSerial lora_serial(6, 5); // TX, RX` and sending data `lora_serial.println("AT+SEND=1,6,alarm\r");` when a button is pressed. Again, this seems to work as I'm successfully receiving this data on the Pi.

Raspberry Pi Side: This is where things get a little weird and I'm sure my Python script needs a bit of tweaking.

```
 import serial
 from time import sleep
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

 # Setup Signal LED
 GPIO.setwarnings(False)
 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

 red = 22
 blue = 16

 GPIO.setup(red, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
 GPIO.setup(blue, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)

 # Attach Lora Module to UART pins on Pi (8 & 10)
 lora = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", 115200)

 alarmState = False
 string = ''

 try:
         while True:
                 print("Polling For Input...")
                 # If we have incoming data, read it
                 if lora.inWaiting() > 0:
                         data = lora.readline()

                         # If the incoming data isn't empty, see if it triggers an alarm
                         if (data != ''):
                                 final = data.decode('utf-8')
                                 # If we receive "alarm", trigger alarm state
                                 print("RECEIVED: {}".format(final)) # Prints "+RCV=0,6,alarm,-45,53"
                                 sleep(1)
                                 data = ''
                                 # Commented out for triggering Error: "[Errno 5] Input/output error"
                                 #lora.flushInput()

                                 # If received message contains "alarm", trigger Alarm
                                 if "alarm" in final:
                                         alarmState = True
                                         print("ALARM STATE")
                                         GPIO.output(blue, GPIO.HIGH)
                                         GPIO.output(red, GPIO.LOW)
                                         string = "AT+SEND=0,6,alarm"
                                         lora.write(string.encode("utf-8"))
                                         final = ''


                 if (alarmState):
                         sleep(1)
                         # Give option to clear alarm in terminal
                         output = input("Clear State? (y): ")

                         if (output == "y"):
                                 string = "AT+SEND=0,6,clear\r" # Sends "clear" to clear alarm state
                                 lora.write(string.encode("utf-8"))
                                 alarmState = False
                                 string = ""
                                 output = ""
                                 GPIO.output(red, GPIO.HIGH)
                                 GPIO.output(blue, GPIO.LOW)
                                 continue
                         elif (output == 'exit'):
                                 lora.close()
                                 exit()
                         else:
                                 output = ''
                 sleep(1)

 except KeyboardInterrupt:
         print("\rExiting...")
         GPIO.output(red, GPIO.HIGH)
         GPIO.output(blue, GPIO.HIGH)
```

So this script runs and will receive data, `"+RCV=0,6,alarm,-45,53"`, but it also sometimes receives the data out of order, such as `,-45,53D: +RCV=0,6,alarm`, which is weird. Additionally, while this Pi is Polling for input, it will receive AT Errors, as shown here:
[image]

Sometimes +ERR=1, sometimes +ERR=4. I know what these errors mean, I'm just not sure why I'm receiving them. Seems like noise that is most likely on the Pi-side of things, but I'm not 100% sure.

Lastly, as stated in the code, I have commented out some of the code that sends output FROM the Pi, back to the Arduino (including flush commands) because it immediately throws an error, `[Errno 5] Input/output error`. I imagine that this is because I'm not writing out properly. That part I'm a little fuzzy on. I'm basically following the same format for BLE, which I've gotten working successfully. I figured this would be the same because it's communicating via UART, but apparently not.

So, if anyone has any ideas, I'd be very grateful.

Best,

Joe

**UPDATE:** By running the `sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@USB0.service`
command, the phantom notifications have been greatly reduced.

I'm still trying to figure out how to send data back to the Arduino because `serial.write()` does not seem to be working

Comment: I have the same issue with ESP32 and RLYR890. +ERR=1 means the incoming transmission was not properly terminated, i.e. with carriage return followed by new line.